# Convergence Locally in Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-number-theory

As far as I understand when we say uniformly, it means we are indicating an area where the function converges, isn't is always local when something converges uniformly?
Please explain what does locally convergence mean.
This question is related to my previous questions [my previous questions (click here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423104/the-epsilon-delta-concept-for-convergence-of-zeta-ms)

Comment: I am perplexed by the fact that  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges uniformly locally in $(0,\infty)$ but $\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right|  $ does not which is exactly same as removing $ n $ terms  from $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$!! am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence), local uniform convergence of a sequence of functions $(f_n)$  in a metric space $E$ means that for every $x \in E$ there exists an open ball $B(x,r)$ such that the sequence converges uniformly on $B(x,r) \cap E$. Uniform convergence on $E$ implies local convergence, but the converse may not be true.

For example, the well known series $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges uniformly locally in $(0,\infty)$. For any $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $r > 0$, we have $\frac{|y|^k}{k!} < \frac{(x+r)^k}{k!}$ for all $y \in (x-r,x+r) \cap (0,\infty)$  and uniform convergence follows by the Weierstrass M-test.  However, convergence is not uniform for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ since

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right| \geqslant\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{x^k}{k!}\geqslant \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\frac{nx^n}{(2n)!} = +\infty $$

Comment: I am perplexed by the fact that  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges uniformly locally in $(0,\infty)$ but $\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right|  $ does not which is exactly same as removing $ n $ terms  from $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$!! am I missing something?

Comment: @Andrew. For the sequence of partial sums $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$ to converge uniformly to $e^x$ on $(0, \infty)$ we must have for any $\epsilon > 0$ that $|S_n(x) - e^x| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$ and ALL $x \in (0,\infty)$ where $N$ is not dependent on $x$.  This means the supremum of $|S_n(x) - e^x|$ over $(0, \infty)$ must converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ and I showed that is not the case.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the convergence is not uniform because for at least one $\epsilon > 0$ and any $n$ no matter how large we can find a large $x \in (0,\infty)$ such that $|S_n(x) - e^x| > \epsilon$. This is always possible for this sequence in the unbounded interval $(0, \infty)$ but not in a bounded interval (where uniform convergence holds by Weierstrass).  By choosing $x$ such that $x^n = (2n)!$ above we see that $|S_n(x) - e^x| > n$ which clearly does not converge to $0$.